# How can i join between two databases in Interbase?

Tags: sql, database, join, interbase

I have two interbase databases, and i want to make join between. 
Long time ago i use MS-SQL database, and there i did that.

How can i make similar in InterBase database?
Thanks answer so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in InterBase. InterBase does not support such heterogeneous joins in SQL.

Comment: You have to do it in your application code. Or combine the DBs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference manual for [InterBase XE SQL](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/interbase/IBXEUpdate2/LangRef.pdf).  It says that InterBase is close to the SQL-92 standard syntax.  That is, the same JOIN syntax that you used with Microsoft SQL Server should work for you here.